# Modelling an ER Diagram

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship

The idea is to design a simple ER diagram for a small application.

The application is a question-answer system. Every user should be able to ask question in text format, and then other users can post answers using image.

At the end, the user who asked the question should be able to select an image to be the correct answer.

So the design that I have so far is that three tables:

- USER with attributes id, username, phone, location, realname, password.
- QUESTION with attributes id, desription, time, status.
- IMAGE with attributes id, address

There are many-to-one relationships between IMAGE and USER and between QUESTION and USER.

However, I don't know how should the relationship between IMAGE and QUESTION looks like.

Should there be a one-to-one relationship between them? Is that a good design?

Thanks

Comment: and how do you differentiate between a user which as a question and one that answer ? also since 1 QUESTION can have Many IMAGE as answers, its a also a one-to-many relationship

Comment: Are you storing the answer to the question? Is there a Question and a QuestionAnswer table?

Comment: @MimiEAM A user who asked question cannot answer his/her own question. So that would be how I differentiate between user as a asker and user as an answerer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user should be able to select an image to be the correct answer to a question, this implies there should be multiple images available to select - so no, a one-to-one relationship between the two is not a good idea.

If any given image is only ever going to be used in one question, then this would suggest a one-to-many relationship from question to image. If the same image can be used in many questions, then this implies a many-to-many relationship.

Of course, you would need to have a "selected image" attribute on the question table.

Comment: Would it be better to have a ternary relationship or a aggregation instead of a triangle kind of inter-relationship between the entities?

Comment: @hydrology: Where there are many-to-many relationships between entities (in relational modelling), you should have a link entity between them which has a many-to-one relationship with each of the linked entities - so (for example) if there was a many-to-many relationship between question and image, then there ought to be a question-image link entity between them. (In this example the link entity might correspond to an "Offered Answers" entity, which hasn't been included in the question.)

Answer (score 0):

```
USER with attributes id, username, phone, location, realname, password.
QUESTION with attributes id, desription, time, status.
IMAGE with attributes id, address

Image_question 1:n ( One question can have multiples images)

User_questions 1:n
```

Comment: While this code may solve the asker's problem, it would be preferable to explain how it works and what are the differences between it and what the asker has tried (if (s)he has tried anything at all).